# PHP - flock() weird behavior

Tags: php, flock

I have 2 scripts with the same part:

```
//wczytanie mappingu drużyn do tabeli
  $plik_z_mappingiem = 'team_mapping.csv';
  $znak_podzialu = ';';
  if (! file_exists($plik_z_mappingiem) || ! is_readable($plik_z_mappingiem)) return FALSE;
  $naglowek = NULL;
  $tabela_druzyn = array();
  if (($handle = fopen($plik_z_mappingiem, 'r')) !== FALSE){
    if (flock($plik_z_mappingiem, LOCK_SH)){
      while (($wiersz = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $znak_podzialu)) !== FALSE){
        if (! $naglowek) $naglowek = $wiersz;
        else $tabela_druzyn[] = array_combine($naglowek, $wiersz);
      }
    }
    flock($plik_z_mappingiem, LOCK_UN);
    fclose($handle);
  }
```

The only difference is that 1 script is in the same folder as team_mapping.csv
and it's working without any isses.

2nd script is in another folder so $plik_z_mappingiem is changed accordingly:

```
$plik_z_mappingiem = "../data/team_mapping.csv";
```

And I get this error:
flock() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in XXX on line 23

```
23: if (flock($plik_z_mappingiem, LOCK_SH)){
```

I should also add that without this if in line 23 whole script runs properly, it creates the table to path to file is correct.

Comment: I would have thought you should use `flock()` on the file handle and not the name - `flock($handle, LOCK_SH)`.

Comment: now I'm even more confused. Well it's working but why 1st script is working and not showing errors? OK I will dig into it. 

THANKS a lot for such a quick answer!

Comment: You need to extract and provide a [mcve]. Chances are, you'll find your mistake doing that. Also, take the [tour] and read [ask].